# how to compile c code for vle powerpc using gnu gcc

Tags: gcc, powerpc

i want to compile my c code in vle PowerPc instructions. how can i do so using gnu gcc or codebench csgnu gcc? i tried `-eabi=vle` but the resulting code did not contain valid vle instructions.

thanx

Comment: GCC now lacks VLE support. Binutils submission was completed by James Lemke, and some patches were prepared for GCC in 2012, but AFAIC, they weren't approved yet. May be state of affairs changed? Why do you think, that you can use VLE -- any docs, or so?

Comment: no, i just needed to compile part of an existing rtos with csgnu.